# Ubuntu USB Wifi found in lsusb but not in iwconfig

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb

My ASUSTek 802.11ac can be seen in `lsusb` but not in `iwconfig`

The `iwconfig` returns:
`lo    no wireless extensions.`

This USB wifi was working previously on my Ubuntu setup and I have testing on Windows using the same Laptop (where I have my USB) and it is working on the Windows.

Not sure what happened to it. It won't even blink the light but on the windows OS it will blink the lights and also work.

Any help?

Comment: `lsusb` shows the raw devices connected to the USB port, working or now... The most likely case here is the WiFi chipset is not supported in the default kernel. What does that line from `lsusb` look like?

Comment: @acejavelin `Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0b05:184c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 802.11ac NIC`. It used to work but now suddenly not working. The kernel is 5.11.0-38-generic

Comment: You probably need to update the driver... https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu This driver is not included in the kernel by default, it has to be manually added.

Comment: @acejavelin so I did the compilation again and followed the REAME. I have `wlo1` in the `iwconfig` but the wifi is not working yet. Also the `insmod 88x2bu.ko` gives the error the the operation is not permitted.

Comment: @acejavelin Its working now. It has to download the new version 5.8 and I was using the older one on my system. Once I did it with the new version now it works!